# Mac audio stops when stopping at breakpoint in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan

I've encountered this issue a while back, but it kinda fixed itself without me even noticing when it stopped.
Today I realized that while listening to youtube, when entering a breakpoint in Xcode, or simply just pausing the app by tapping the pause button in Xcode, the sound stops, while the video continues.
If I pause the video and then click play while in the breakpoint, it does nothing besides changing the Play Button and stays like that until I continue running the app normally.
Has anyone encountered such a problem, and is it something you could fix?

* I have not tried restarting yet, since I have quite a number of apps open and in use.

Comment: Happening to me right now.

Comment: it's still happening every once in a while... it seems like it's something eating up the processor, but still nothing sure

Comment: I'm still having this problem. Any solution?

Comment: still no fix ... i'm considering a fresh osx install on my computer, maybe that could fix it.

Comment: After an Xcode restart (actually, it crashed), this problem disappeared.

Comment: hmm, it still happens to me after lots of crashes and restarts... i kind of got used to it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode keeps pausing my music](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709313/xcode-keeps-pausing-my-music)

Comment: Thanks @CAMOBAP I will try this when I get the time. It does seem to have a good solution that might work

Comment: happens to me with Xcode 12

Comment: yeah, this problem went away for some time now, I couldn't find a fault or a fix for it.

Comment: its annoying, @apple please fix it

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it would be a bug in Xcode that's stopping some obscure background thread for some reason.